# Fly Recycler item cell to destination View on click?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, uiviewanimation

I am trying to build layout, in which there will be recycler view on the top . and TextView at bottom side (destination view) . [Image-1]

[image]

When We click on any of the recycler item , it should fly from the item position to the destination position , i have done the similar task in iOS idea was :

1. Create snapshot view of clicked item .
2. Add Snapshot view on current page .
3. Fly Animation by changing it's `x`,`y` and `height` and `width` (`CGRect` in iOS ) towards the Destination view
4. When animation is finished then removing snapshot view from page .(removeFromSuperView in iOS)

[image]

**Problem** :

I am not able to do this is Android ,

1. 1st problem is , how can i create dynamic view on activity , my root view is `CoordinatorLayout`, and then animating
2. The animating the view from item position to destination view.

> ```
> @Override
>     public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
>       // Fly This view to the destination
>     }
> ```

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-eauto"
    xmlns:app2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app2:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="294dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app2:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app2:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app2:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDestination"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="165dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="166dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="166dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawble_round"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app2:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app2:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app2:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If anyone want to animate like this , you can do via this library https://github.com/matrixdevz/FlyToCartAnimation